# Block users coming from a particular URL after clicking banner ad

Tags: php

I want to block users coming from a particular URL. our adbanner is shown in many websites. People who click our  banner on a website are directed to our registration page. I don't want the page to be shown for people who click our ad on a particular website say http://abc.com. How can I implement this restriction ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check their [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

Comment: depended on the adserver this will not work, in most adservers your HTTP referrer will be the adserver not the page where the banner is clicked. the only way would be to have an parameter eg. refID from the adserver to let you know from which source the click orginated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` for the domain you want to restrict.

Something like this can work:

```
$bad_domain = 'abc.com';
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $bad_domain) !== false) {
    // block user, they came from $bad_domain
}
```

It's easy to spoof the referer string in a browser, or install a plugin to leave it blank but many people don't have such restrictions.  Also, if they clicked from an `https` page, the referer is also not sent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) but it's not 100% guaranteed to work.